# Finding a volume of a region that is bounded by planes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

I am trying to find the volume of a region bounded by the following planes:

$4x+2y+4z=6$

$y=x$

$x=0$

$z=0$

I tried to first solve for $z = \frac{6 - 4x - 2y}{4}$

And then I tried to set up a double integral with this function with bounds of $\left[y, \frac{-y+3}{2}\right]$ for $x$ and $[0, 1]$ for $y$.

I got these bounds by graphing on the x-y plane the plane $4x+2y+4z = 6$, since when $y, z = 0$, $x = 3/2$, and when $x, z = 0, y = 3$. I then found the equation for this line in the x-y plane, which is $y = -2x + 3$. I solved for $x = \frac{-y+3}{2}$, which would be the lower bound, and the upper bound would be $y$, because of the plane $y = x$.

I then projected this intersection onto just the y-axis, where $y = 1$, which would be the upper bound.

I get the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{-y+3}{2}}^{y} \frac{6 - 4x - 2y}{4} \,dx\,dy$

Is this process totally wrong? I feel like it is, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would identify all the vertices (corners) formed by the meeting of three planes.   Visualizing those corners will help you set up the limits of integration correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct but the bounds are not correct.

If you go in the order $dx, dy$, you will have to split it into two integrals. So the order I suggest is $dy, dx$.

We can rewrite $4x+2y+4z=6$ as $2x+y+2z=3$.

The volume is bound between planes $x = 0, z = 0, x = y \ $ and $ \ 2x+y+2z=3$.

If you look at the diagram, the area bound in $xy$ ($z=0$) plane, it is between lines $x = 0, y = x \ $ and $ \ 2x + y = 3$.

[image]

The bounds are $x \leq y \leq 3-2x$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

So the correct integral to find volume of the region is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_x^{3-2x} \dfrac{3-2x-y}{2} \ dy \ dx$